# echo %time% duplicate outputs

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt

I have a command that adds the timestamp at the beginning and the end (`echo %time% & #other command# & echo %time%`).
However, the `%time%` will be the same, regardless of how long the command took to execute.

example output:

```
Time start: 19:48:31.75

Pinging google.com [2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e: time=13ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e: time=13ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e: time=9ms
Reply from 2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e: time=10ms

Ping statistics for 2a00:1450:400e:80c::200e:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 13ms, Average = 11ms

Time end: 19:48:31.76
```

Is there a way to have this work, still within one line?

Thanks

Comment: command & command execution is only when true, why not use semicolon ; it execute regardless

Comment: @djdomi i tried this, but writing it like `echo %time%; ping google.com; echo %time%` 
or even with quotes, it doesn't work. It sees the semicolon as a part of the command, rather than closing it

Comment: @djdomi `;` does no work in cmd, a single `&` continues execution while `&&` does not

Comment: @MichaelHampton: The difference is .01 seconds while it shoud be more than 4 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

CMD expands variables and then executes each line.
That means that

```
echo %time% & ping 127.0.0.1 & echo %time%
```

is first expanded, and then executed

There is also "delayed expansion"
[Here is some example usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file), [and even more detailed](https://superuser.com/questions/1569594/how-does-delayed-expansion-works-in-batch-script)
This however only works in a cmd file, and not on commandline

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo !time! & ping 127.0.0.1 & echo !time!
```

Continue searching [maybe cmd /V](https://superuser.com/a/950944/250231) can be used:

```
cmd /V /C "echo %time% & ping 127.0.0.1 & echo !time!"
```

It gives expected result for me, but there might be gotchas preventing some use cases.

Comment: *[... and even more detailed](https://superuser.com/questions/1569594/how-does-delayed-expansion-works-in-batch-script)* 
I liked the support reference.... d:)

Comment: I am in my mac now, so no way to tes, but. maybe **`call`** can do this too:  `echo %time% & ping 127.0.0.1 & call echo %time%`...

Comment: @It that will not work since the variables is evaluated first there as well, you must have the delayed expansion if you run it on same line (or block `()`)

Comment: for this i write *maybe*